# Firebase is saying "the link provided isn't valid for email/link sign in. Check the link by calling isSignInWithEmailLink"

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, uikit, firebase-dynamic-links

In my `SignInViewController` I have created an `ActionCodeSettings` object that contains the dynamic link domain and the url with the https scheme attached to the URL string, I assume that this is the "sign in link" that firebase is referring too. In another viewcontroller, once the sign-in button is pressed the firebase isSignin:withEmail method is supposed to be executed to determine whether or not the email link is proper, from there my signIn:withEmail method is supposed to execute but I get the error mentioned above in the question.

Here is my SignInViewController code (only copying piece from inside a function):

```
else {
        view.endEditing(true)
        let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
        actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID("com.IMHOTECHP.GiftMe")
        actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
        actionCodeSettings.dynamicLinkDomain = "imhotechp.com"
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: "https://imhotechp.com")
        
        Auth.auth().sendSignInLink(toEmail: EmailField.text!, actionCodeSettings: actionCodeSettings){ error in
            if let error = error { self.handleSignUpError(error: error)
                                    return }}
```

Here is my other ViewController code, this view controller is shown once above function is executed:

```
  let link = "https://imhotechp.com"


func handlePasswordlessSignIn(_ url: URL){
    let emailvalue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Email")
    if Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link){
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailvalue! , link: link) { (user, error) in
       if error == nil && user != nil {
        if (Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)!{
            print("User verified")
        } else {
            print("User not verified")
        }}}}}
```

For some reason my isSignIn:withEmail function doesn't pass at all which in turn doesn't allow me to sign in. Any direction?

Below is my app delegate code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    NSLog("Ok this works")
    return true
}

internal func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])
-> Bool {
    NSLog("Ok this works")
    return true
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    NSLog("Ok this works")
    return true
```

After following steps in the comments, the code fully runs but am getting these errors after I close the app.

[image]

Comment: Where does a guy named 'link' come from in Auth.auth().isSignIn(withEmailLink: link)?

Comment: so sorry it is a global variable contained in the file where the handlePasswordlessSignIn is declared as such:  let link = "https://imhotechp.com" @ElTomato

Comment: It sounds to me that you are not setting the right link.

Comment: Show your code from AppDelegate.

Comment: Check now @ElTomato

Comment: Where is your dynamic link in `application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity`...?

Comment: its the 3rd function in the app delegate @ElTomato

Comment: You are not following the intructions written at https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive .

Comment: thanks @ElTomato i followed that now my code runs fully through but I'm getting these type of errors